# In a continuous integration environment, how do teams deal with known minor bugs?

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm asking as a web developer who hasn't yet used Ci.

If a bug is discovered and confirmed but judged to be low priority or difficult to fix, how do teams set up Ci servers to to allow them to continue to work on other issues?

I imagine I would want to write a test to confirm the existence of the bug, and have the CI server run it, but then it seems like it would mark every build as broken. Are there ways to tell Ci servers "yes, we know this test fails, it's likely to keep failing, only alert us if something else fails in a future build or if it stops failing"?

Comment: see also: [Should I intentionally break the build when a bug is found in production?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131006/should-i-intentionally-break-the-build-when-a-bug-is-found-in-production)

Comment: Don't write a test for it if you don't plan to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CI software can quarantine test failures ([quarantine is the word that atlassian use for this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/quarantining-failing-tests-289276886.html), other CI tools may be different). It will record the test failure, but it won't fail the build.

However, the way that I would approach this is to create a bugfix branch, write the test on this bugfix branch so that the branch fails to build. When the bug is addressed in the future, this branch can be updated to the master branch, the tests checked again, and then resolved.